# Accessing GridView Cells Value

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am trying to access the integer value of the first cell but I'm getting this error:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataControlFieldCell' to type 'System.IConvertible'.

And the value i have stored in that cell is an ID like 810

My Code

```
int myID = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[0]);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Cells[0]` returns a `DataControlFieldCell` object, not the cell's value.
Use the cell's `Text` property.

Comment: Ok, that does not help me, what should I use?.. I am new to C#. Thanks

Comment: `Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[0].Text)`

Comment: The value is comming in as blank not sure why it cant find the value its comming as a ""

Comment: @user710502 - I guess the first column of GridView contains linkbutton or something.

Answer (score 4):

```cs
GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[0].Text
```

--or--

```cs
GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[0].Value
```

Makes programmer's life harder with these stupid ambiguities introduced by Microsoft over time.

Answer (score 0):

Try this both of this codes are valued

```
 int SB = Convert.ToInt32(gdTest.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text);

              ---------OR-------

int AS = Convert.ToInt32(gdTest.Rows[1].Cells[1].Text);
```

Answer (score 0):

The recommended approach to retrieve the value of a cell in GridView/FormView is to use ExtractValuesFromCell() method. See an example below:

```
foreach(var row in GridView.Rows) 
{
    // retrieve all cell values in a row as a ordered dictionary.
    IOrderedDictionary cellValues = new OrderedDictionary();
    foreach(DataControlFieldCell cell in row.Cells)
    {      
            cell.ContainingField.ExtractValuesFromCell(cellValues, cell, row.RowState, true);
    }

    // now do something with the cellValues for e.g read the columns value
    // like - cellValues["EmployeeName"]
}
```

The returned values are strings and can be converted with the help of System.Convert class.

Comment: To elaborate, this way gives the old values stored when the gridview is originally binded/created, but not the new value typed into the input box when you are updating